# CSS only solution for collapsible navbar with animation sliding open/closed?

Tags: html, css, animation

EDIT: Code Pen example - https://codepen.io/earleyj1/pen/YjpNZK (You need to shrink the browser window down for responsive nav)

I'm looking for a CSS ONLY solution for a collapsible navbar that has opening/closing animation. The height of said navbar when opened could be anything.

I'm writing my styles in SASS, but they get compiled to a minified CSS file before I use it.

```css
.navbar-dropdown {
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    li {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      a {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: block;
        color: $nav-anchor;
        font-weight: 300;
        padding: 1rem;
        text-decoration: none;
        transition: background .5s;
        &:hover,
        &:focus,
        &:focus-within {
          color: $nav-anchor-hover
        }
      }
      ul {
        background: $nav-dropdown-background;
        display: none;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 56px;
        min-width: 10rem;
      }
      &:hover,
      &:focus,
      &:focus-within {
        background: $nav-hover;
        ul {
          display: block;
          li {
            display: list-item;
            padding: .5rem;
            &:hover,
            &:focus,
            &:focus-within {
              background: $nav-dropdown-hover;
            }
            a {
              color: $nav-anchor-child;
              &:hover,
              &:focus,
              &:focus-within {
                color: $nav-anchor-child-hover
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/

.nav-toggle {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  background: #18453b;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: none;
}


/*Hide checkbox*/

#nav-toggle {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: anim-back .3s ease-in-out;
}


/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/

#nav-toggle:checked~#menu {
  display: block;
}


/*Responsive Styles*/

@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
  #menu {
    display: none;
  }
  /*Create vertical spacing*/
  li {
    margin-bottom: 1px;
  }
  /*Make all menu links full width*/
  ul li,
  li a {
    width: 100%;
  }
  /*Display 'nav toggle'*/
  .nav-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-container">
  <label for="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle button">Menu</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle" role="button">
  <div id="menu" class="container">
    <nav id="" class="navbar navbar-dropdown">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Students</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Faculty & Staff</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Alumni & Friends</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Research</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Diversity</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can get the nav to collapse and expand just fine, but I'm looking at a way to animate that menu opening/closing when the button is clicked to open or close it with ONLY CSS.

Comment: That's not CSS... Looks more like LESS.

Comment: Yes, but it gets compiled to CSS before I use it.

Comment: Just FYI, when you put something in a snippet, most of us are expecting to be able to click Run code snippet and see the problem reproduced.

Comment: Ah, gotcha, sorry, i was just trying to post the markup and style code. I added a link to a code pen

Comment: @HereticMonkey you can click the green bar I put it in the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

> The height of said navbar when opened could be anything.

I can think of few solutions.

The **first** consist to hide the `#menu ul` by translating it.

**It works with any height.**

```css
#menu {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#menu ul {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition: transform .3s;
  margin: 0;
}
#nav-toggle:checked ~ #menu ul {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<label for="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle button">Menu</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle" role="button">
    <div id="menu" class="container">
        <nav id="" class="navbar navbar-dropdown">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">About</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Students</a>
                    <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Faculty & Staff</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Alumni & Friends</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Research</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Diversity</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Here is an older solution **if you know** that the height won't be biger than ***x***.

As you know, in CSS you can't animate from `display: block;` to `display: none;`.

A **simple trick** is to animate the `max-height` property from **0** to a **value big enough**.

In your exemple :

```css
#menu { 
  max-height: 0; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  transition: max-height .5s;
}
#nav-toggle:checked ~ #menu {
  max-height: 800px; /* A value big enough for your menu*/
}
```

```html
 <label for="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle button">Menu</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle" role="button">
    <div id="menu" class="container">
        <nav id="" class="navbar navbar-dropdown">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">About</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Students</a>
                    <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Faculty & Staff</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Alumni & Friends</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Research</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Diversity</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This ALMOST gets there, but in your first example, where the height isn't known, see how there is a scrollbar when the nav is closed? The<nav> element is still there, taking up space, so any content below the navbar remains pushed down.

Comment: I'm ultimately trying to get it to behave similar to a Bootstrap nav bar on collapse/open, but with ONLY using CSS.

Comment: @JesseEarley My bad, I was expecting `#menu` to be `position: absolute;` or `fixed`. It will work if it's the case.

Comment: That seems to create an issue.with a 100% width dropdown (when a background color is applied) in that it breaks out of the parent.

Comment: @JesseEarley Well at this point, it's just a matter of positioning, but without the full markup, it will be hard to be more helpful